# How to create gridView 2 columns with this layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I already created the gridView with two columns, also the design, but it doesn't look as expected, I'd like to have to items per columns that looks like this :

[image]

The first square is an image, then below is a `view` to separate them, below there's a `LinearLayout` with `orientation:vertical` so I can add 2 fields, the second one should be `maxColumns:2`, but the problem is when I create the little square of the right, it's not shown because the left `LinearLayout` is occupying all the space, I don't know if it's because I added `layout_widht="200dp"`.

This is how it looks now :

[image]

And this is my layout

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                   xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                   android:id="@+id/card_view"
                                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                   card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                                   card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linear_main_item"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
    >


        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_item_image"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="2dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/relative_text_parent">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/linear_text" android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/description"
                            tools:text="Seasonal Black IPA."
                    />

                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                        android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp">
                </View>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/percentage"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        tools:text="5.4%" android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>




        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

change your code something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_main_item"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_item_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:text="What I'm doing wrong?"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="Seasonal Black IPA." />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"></View>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/percentage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                tools:text="5.4%" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to achieve same UI

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_main_item"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_item_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
                android:text="What I'm doing wrong?"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="Seasonal Black IPA." />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".02"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".28"
android:gravity="center">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/percentage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:text="5.4%" />
```

[image: Screen shot]